# using quarkus jwt token in micronaut application

Tags: jwt, quarkus, micronaut

I have two microservices

1. auth-service developed using Quarkus to generate JWT token.
2. i developed the 2nd service using Micronaut (service1). I  need to authenticate end points using auth-service. Can anyone please explain how to achieve it.

Please find the both services in the following

https://github.com/microservices-j/auth-service

https://github.com/microservices-j/service1

I generated the token using auth-service

and i pass the token into service1, but i am getting unauthorized.

```
> > Task :run  __  __ _                                  _    |  \/  (_) ___ _ __ ___  _ __   __ _ _   _| |_  | |\/| | |/ __| '__/ _ \| '_ \ / _` | | | | __| | |  | | | (__| | | (_) | | | | (_| | |_| | |_  |_|  |_|_|\___|_|  \___/|_| |_|\__,_|\__,_|\__|   Micronaut (v3.6.3)
> 
> 12:49:25.382 [main] DEBUG i.m.s.a.AuthenticationModeCondition -
> CookieBasedAuthenticationModeCondition is not fulfilled because
> micronaut.security.authentication is not one of [cookie, idtoken].
> 12:49:25.678 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup
> completed in 1157ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8082
> 12:50:13.738 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.a.AuthenticationModeCondition -
> CookieBasedAuthenticationModeCondition is not fulfilled because
> micronaut.security.authentication is not one of [cookie, idtoken].
> 12:50:13.755 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token in
> Authorization header 12:50:13.755 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2]
> DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET, /swagger-ui,
> no token found. 12:50:13.759 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.rules.IpPatternsRule - One or more of the IP patterns
> matched the host address [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]. Continuing request
> processing. 12:50:13.762 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.rules.AbstractSecurityRule - The given roles [[isAnonymous()]]
> matched one or more of the required roles [[isAnonymous()]]. Allowing
> the request 12:50:13.762 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET
> /swagger-ui. The rule provider
> io.micronaut.security.rules.ConfigurationInterceptUrlMapRule
> authorized the request. 12:50:14.734 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2]
> DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token
> in Authorization header 12:50:14.734 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2]
> DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Request GET,
> /swagger/service1-0.0.yml, no token found. 12:50:14.735
> [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.rules.IpPatternsRule - One or more of the IP patterns
> matched the host address [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]. Continuing request
> processing. 12:50:14.736 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.rules.InterceptUrlMapRule - No url map pattern exact match found
> for path [/swagger/service1-0.0.yml] and method [GET]. Searching in
> patterns with no defined method. 12:50:14.736
> [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG i.m.s.rules.InterceptUrlMapRule
> - Url map pattern found for path [/swagger/service1-0.0.yml]. Comparing roles. 12:50:14.736 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.rules.AbstractSecurityRule - The given roles [[isAnonymous()]]
> matched one or more of the required roles [[isAnonymous()]]. Allowing
> the request 12:50:14.736 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Authorized request GET
> /swagger/service1-0.0.yml. The rule provider
> io.micronaut.security.rules.ConfigurationInterceptUrlMapRule
> authorized the request. 12:50:38.395 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2]
> DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.HttpHeaderTokenReader - Looking for bearer token
> in Authorization header 12:50:38.395 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2]
> DEBUG i.m.s.t.reader.DefaultTokenResolver - Token
> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJwbXMiLCJzdWIiOiJkZW1vLnVzZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE2NjMzNDY5OTcsImV4cCI6MTY2MzM0NzI5NywianRpIjoiOGM1Mzc2ODMtOGM4Yy00MjgyLWFiYWUtMTU2Yzg3MjgzNGZhIn0.SxCAUxryW315Q3WlRSk6PypUh9s6K-Wce3zrB5Hmycs
> found in request GET /hello 12:50:38.418
> [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.t.jwt.validator.JwtValidator - Validating signed JWT
> 12:50:38.473 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Attributes: sub=>demo.user,
> iss=>pms, exp=>Fri Sep 16 12:54:57 EDT 2022, iat=>Fri Sep 16 12:49:57
> EDT 2022, jti=>8c537683-8c8c-4282-abae-156c872834fa 12:50:38.474
> [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.security.rules.IpPatternsRule - One or more of the IP patterns
> matched the host address [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]. Continuing request
> processing. 12:50:38.474 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] DEBUG
> i.m.s.rules.AbstractSecurityRule - None of the given roles
> [[isAnonymous(), isAuthenticated()]] matched the required roles [[]].
> Rejecting the request 12:50:38.474 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2]
> DEBUG i.m.security.filters.SecurityFilter - Unauthorized request GET
> /hello. The rule provider
> io.micronaut.security.rules.SecuredAnnotationRule rejected the
> request. <===========--> 85% EXECUTING [6m 23s]
> > :run
> > IDLE
```

Comment: you need to provide further information. what did you do so far? how does your Micronaut config looks like. Don’t expect Stackoverflow to do the coding for you

Comment: I have added code in the github and details added in main question.

Comment: Can you add the log output? Set in your logback.xml a logger `<logger name=„io,micronaut.security“ level=„TRACE“/>`. This question still needs more details.

Comment: i have updated the log in the question

Answer (score 0):

In your Quarkus application your are generating a signed JWT.

```java
ApplicationScoped
@PermitAll
@Path("/login")
class LoginResource {

    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/")
    @POST
    fun login() : Response {

        val token =  Jwt
            .issuer("pms")
            .subject("demo.user")
            .sign()

        return Response.ok(token).build()
    }
}
```

In your Quarks application properties you use a Public/Private key pair to sign the JWT.

```
quarkus.http.port=8081

smallrye.jwt.sign.key.location=/Users/bala/labs/auth-service/jwt/privateKey.pem
mp.jwt.verify.issuer=demo
mp.jwt.verify.publickey.location=/Users/bala/labs/auth-service/jwt/publicKey.pem
```

But in the Micronaut microservice you are trying to validate the JWT using a *secret* to validate the JWT.

```yaml
micronaut:
  server:
    port: 8082
  application:
    name: service1
  security:
    authentication: bearer
    basic-auth:
      enabled: false # <-- Add this to disable basic auth
    token:
      jwt:
        signatures:
          secret:
            generator:
              secret: ${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET:pleaseChangeThisSecretForANewOne}
```

Of course this fails.

You have the following two options.

1. The easy one. Make Quarkus generate signed JWT using a secret.
2. The other option. Use the Public Key in Micronaut to validate the JWT (see [RSASignatureConfiguration](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/api/io/micronaut/security/token/jwt/signature/rsa/RSASignatureConfiguration.html))

For option 2) you have to add an addition bean to the application context.

```kotlin
@Singleton
@Named
class MySignatureConfig : RSASignatureConfiguration {
    override fun getPublicKey(): RSAPublicKey {
        val encoded: ByteArray = Base64.getDecoder().decode("<your public key as a string>")

        val keyFactory: KeyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        val keySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded)
        return keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec) as RSAPublicKey
    }
}
```

This will help to validate the JWT.

Additionally this is how Micronaut Security works, in the Basic Authentication Flow. Simply exchange `AuthenticationFetcher` with `TokenAuthenticationFetcher`. The helps debugging the flow.

[image: Authentication Flow]